# synchronize function

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, synchronization

how can i do in C# that my function will be guarded by mutex semaphore a.k.a synchronize function in JAVA

Comment: Are you trying to guard a function, or member data?

Comment: function, actually, it's a function thate write to a file, and it sometimes crashes when trying to do multywright...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want synchronize functions like Java - they're a bad idea because they use a lock construct which other can interfere with. What you want is a lock object. Basically, in the class you want to protect, create a private member variable of type object

```
private readonly object lock_ = new object();
```

Then in any method you need to synchronize, use the lock construct to enter and leave the lock automatically:-

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
    lock(lock_)
    {
         // ...... Do Stuff .........
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought that's what _I_ said.

Comment: ...And an underscore *after* the variable name.  There's a convention I haven't seen before.

Comment: This is the paraphrase version :)

Comment: It won't compile either; no data type on the member variable.

Comment: @John Saunders - I think we submitted around the same time - if you want the glory let me know how to pass it on.


@Robert Harvey - I'm pretty sure I got the underscore after the variable name convention for member variables from reviewing Accelerated C++ by Koenig and Moo. I kind of liked it and started using it in my own code. When we abandoned hungarian it kind of stuck on my team. I like it better than m_ for sure, and underscore before is not legal C++ and I like to use the same conventions everywhere.

Answer (score 10):

There's no good way to do this, except to do it yourself:

```
private readonly object _locker = new object();

public void MyMethod()
{
    lock (_locker) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: There actually is a mutex object; is it a bad idea?

Comment: Mutex is slower than lock (Monitor object).  It's really only meant for cross-process communication and I believe uses the OS built-in mutex functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Thread/UseMethodImplAttributetosynchronizeamethod.htm)

Answer (score 0):

As John said, you can use `lock ()`, which is the same thing as Monitor.Enter and Monitor.Exit.  If you need a cross-process mutex, use the Mutex class.